# saving dropdown list value in database laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, drop-down-menu

I am trying to ask gender of the user in registration form through dropdown list but I am unable to get that value in controller.

Here is my code to register.blade.php

```
<!-- Gender -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 control-label">Gender</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
         <select class="form-control" required="required">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code of `register controller`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'fullname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'dob' => 'required|date',
        'gender' => 'required|string',
        // 'gender' => 'in:male,female'

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    dd($data);
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'fullname' => $data['fullname'],

        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
         'gender' => $data['gender'],

    ]);
}
```

`user model` contains

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password','fullname','dob','gender'
];
```

and the output shown when line  'gender' => 'required|string', is commented in validator function of register controller. Nothing happens when this line is uncommented
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write attribute `name="gender"` in the `select`element.

Without `name` attribute the data is not passed via GET/POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Name for field was missed.

```
<select class="form-control" name="gender" required="required">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```